# Python: sort list based on item and external key

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list as follows:

```
[['a', 123], ['b', 456], ['c', 789]]
```

and the string `cba`

I would like to sort the list based on the first item and the order in which the string `cba` is in:

```
[['c', 789], ['b', 456], ['a', 123]]
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: so you want descending order of the letters? Have you tried anything? Also its bad practice to mix types in lists. You should consider changing the collection type to `tuple`

Comment: So if the string were `bca`, you'd want `[['b', 456], ['c', 789], ['a', 123]]`, right?

Comment: sorry if it's not clear, it's not just descending order based on the first item, but the order of the string as @ShadowRanger mentions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works quite well with `key`-based use of `list.sort`/`sorted`:

```
mylist = [['a', 123], ['b', 456], ['c', 789]]
mykey = 'cba'

mylist.sort(key=lambda x: mykey.index(x[0]))
```

If the key string were huge, repeated `index` calls would be inefficient (make a `dict` that maps value to index in a single pass if that's an issue, e.g. `mykeydict = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(mykey)}`, then `key=lambda x: mykeydict[x[0]]`), but for short to moderate lengths, the `index` call is cheap enough (it's only performed once per item in `mylist`, not for every comparison).